# In applications where heating is not the required from of energy, current is to be kept low as per Joules law. What energy is considered useful?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

As per this paragraph from Wikipedia

"Joule heating is referred to as ohmic heating or resistive heating because of its relationship to Ohm's Law. It forms the basis for the large number of practical applications involving electric heating.

****However, in applications where heating is an unwanted by-product of current use**** the diversion of energy is often referred to as resistive loss."

My question is, "If not in the form of heat, then how else is the use of energy justified? How else is the energy being used?"

Comment: Haven’t you heard of electric motions?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is referring to any use of electric power other than resistive heating. I suppose I could list a few:

1. Electric motors
2. Computers/circuitry
3. LED/fluorescent lighting
4. Radio/communication
5. Lasers
6. Radar/sonar
7. Refrigerators/AC
8. Microwave ovens

...must I go on?

Comment: But how. Any one application with the proces involved will clear the facts

Comment: @Shai hi, I don’t understand your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: Considering the case of Electric motors or Radio/Communication where heat is not intended. So how is electrical energy being used. Is the energy sourced from acceleration of electrons?

Comment: @Shai each of these examples uses electrical energy in different ways (but not for Joule heating). You’ll have to read about them individually. For example, electric motors use magnetic fields in a clever way to spin a rotor, and radios emitters use changing electric currents to emit radio-frequency radiation instead of heat. Then radio receivers collect that radiation, demodulate it at a selected frequency, and convert the energy into sound waves.